# Do I really have to use an Activity class to launch my Service

Tags: service

Creating an Activity with a Service and setting up the bindService.
I thought i could make all this run "hidden" like a background Service - silentely this Service (client) would connect to my PC server waiting for incoming. I read the Service class api dock and cant see any description how to do that. Do I really have to use an Activity class to launch my Service. I know i can launch activity classes from the service if I need.
Can somebody enplane this before i go nuts?

Comment: What platform are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the BroadcastReceiver "actually" doing?

cant wrap my head around the code implementation here.
after reading many questions here and elsewhere about this
getting fragment of clarification I think the method is:
- an apk file which contains a Service an activity and a
  BroadcastReceiver Class.
- action.BOOT_COMPLETED will start only my Service, not the Activity.
  The user can from Main Launcher start Activity for "in app settings" and I Bind
  to Service and Unbind when done

Yea will try this tomorrow after work.